# Go lang Capture Redirect urls and status codes with timeouts

Tags: http, redirect, go

I am trying to make a request to a given url, and capture the redirect urls and their status codes that were followed.

I've tried looking for an answer to my specific question - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577494/how-to-get-the-http-redirect-status-codes-in-golang) came close .

However, I need to also add proxy, user agent and timeouts on the entire connection i.e. No matter how many redirects / proxy latency etc, the amount of time should not exceed X seconds.

I've handled user-agent by setting request header, and proxy by adding it to the Transport struct.
I tried exploring CheckRedirect for redirects - but that gives me only Url, I needed the status code as well, so I had to implement the RoundTrip function.

Everything works well as of now - except for the Timeout.
Heres what I have so far - [playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/m6-ukzykSQ)
I've pasted the relevant code here as well - the playground has a full version with a mock redirect server in place - Unfortunately it panics saying connection refused possibly because of playground restrictions - It works completely locally though.

```
type Redirect struct {
    StatusCode int
    URL string
}

type TransportWrapper struct {
    Transport http.RoundTripper
    Url string
    Proxy string
    UserAgent string
    TimeoutInSeconds int
    FinalUrl string
    RedirectUrls []Redirect
}
// Implementing Round Tripper to capture intermediate urls
func (t *TransportWrapper) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    transport := t.Transport
    if transport == nil {
        transport = http.DefaultTransport
    }

    resp, err := transport.RoundTrip(req)
    if err != nil {
        return resp, err
    }

    // Remember redirects
    if resp.StatusCode >= 300 && resp.StatusCode <= 399 {
        t.RedirectUrls = append(
            t.RedirectUrls, Redirect{resp.StatusCode, req.URL.String()},
        )
    }
    return resp, err
}

func (t *TransportWrapper) Do() (*http.Response, error) {
    t.Transport = &http.Transport{}
    if t.Proxy != "" {
        proxyUrl, err := url.Parse(t.Proxy)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        t.Transport = &http.Transport{Proxy:http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)}
        // HELP
        // Why does this fail
        // t.Transport.Proxy = http.ProxyUrl(proxyUrl)
    }

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: t, // Since I've implemented RoundTrip I can pass this
        // Timeout: t.TimeoutInSeconds * time.Second, // This Fails 
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", t.Url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if t.UserAgent != "" {
        req.Header.Set("User-Agent", t.UserAgent)
    }

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    t.FinalUrl = resp.Request.URL.String()
    return resp, nil
}

func startClient() {
    t := &TransportWrapper {
        Url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/temporary/redirect?num=5",
        // Proxy
        // UserAgent
        // Timeout
    }

    _, err := t.Do()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Intermediate Urls: \n")
    for i, v := range t.RedirectUrls {
        fmt.Printf("[%d] %s\n", i, v)
    }

}
```

Question 1 : How do I Add the timeout ?

Attempt #1 :

```
client := &http.Client{ Transport: t, Timeout: myTimeout }
```

But Go complains saying " *main.TransportWrapper doesn't support CancelRequest; Timeout not supported "

Attempt #2 :

```
// Adding a CancelRequest
func (t *TransportWrapper) CancelRequest(req *http.Request) {
    dt := http.DefaultTransport
    dt.CancelRequest(req)
}
```

But Go complains saying "dt.CancelRequest undefined (type http.RoundTripper has no field or method CancelRequest)"

How do I implement this CancelRequest without doing too much and just let default CancelRequest take over ?

Question 2 : Have I gone down a bad path and is there an alternative to solving the problem ,

Given a Url, Proxy, UserAgent and Timeout - return the response along with the redirect urls and their status codes followed to get there.

I hope I've worded this appropriately.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already a hook for checking redirects, [`Client.CheckRedirect`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client).

You can supply a callback to do what you want.

If you really want to create you're own transport to extend other functionality, you would need to supply a `CancelRequest` method like the error says to handle `Client.Timeout`.

```
func (t *TransportWrapper) CancelRequest(req *Request) {
    t.Transport.CancelRequest(req)
}
```

More commonly, you would embed the `Transport`, so that all the methods and fields are automatically promoted. You should avoid writable fields in the transport however, since it's expected to be safe to use concurrently, otherwise you should have all access protected with a mutex, or you must make sure it's only used in one goroutine.

A minimal example would look like:

```
type TransportWrapper struct {
    *http.Transport
    RedirectUrls []Redirect
}

func (t *TransportWrapper) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    transport := t.Transport
    if transport == nil {
        transport = http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport)
    }

    resp, err := transport.RoundTrip(req)
    if err != nil {
        return resp, err
    }

    // Remember redirects
    if resp.StatusCode >= 300 && resp.StatusCode <= 399 {
        fmt.Println("redirected")
        t.RedirectUrls = append(
            t.RedirectUrls, Redirect{resp.StatusCode, req.URL.String()},
        )
    }
    return resp, err
}
```

And you can then use the timeout in the client:

```
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: &TransportWrapper{
        Transport: http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport),
    },
    Timeout: 5 * time.Second,
}
```

Comment: The `Client.CheckRedirect` allows me to capture redirect URLs, but I would also like to know their status codes, i.e. 301, 302 etc, for which I believe [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24577494/how-to-get-the-http-redirect-status-codes-in-golang) says I need to create my own RoundTripper. I tried the CancelRequest here but that made no difference - I made the server sleep 5 seconds, and timeout at one second, and still no luck. The updated code with the sleep and cancelrequest is [here](http://play.golang.org/p/zOxvQdCjOz)

Comment: @AbhishekShivanna: I'm not sure why the CancelRequest doesn't work for you without the code and error, but I put in a minimal example. I would also avoid putting the `Do`method in the `Transport`, since that's belongs to the `Client`, and makes the code confusing with a circular reference between the two.

Comment: Thanks Alot ! I've decided to go with the approach of embedding. When you talk about concurrency protection, is it because the same transport wrapper might be used in another client as well ? I plan on creating a new transport wrapper and client for each URL that I want all its redirects for. In this case I shouldn't need locks right ? Or are the locks for some internal magic and go routines that the default transport performs ?

Comment: I made the server sleep for 5 seconds before giving a response. This causes a `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` . It points to `t.reqMu.Lock()` [line 280 of transport.go](http://golang.org/src/net/http/transport.go)  .

Comment: It also seems to be calling CancelRequest even after I have got a response. I've tested this by running a sleep after the request has finished successfully. I figured out that this is because I did not do a `resp.Body.Close()`. On a successful run, I can do this, but what about in the round tripper  ? I wouldnt want to close the body there right ?

Comment: @AbhishekShivanna: the nil pointer dereference is because you're not assigning a transport to your wrapper. I added a default assignment in my example now. You *always* need to close the response Body. Yes, you also need to read the entire body to finish the request, or the timeout will get called. You should also try to read any body (up to a limit) in the redirect responses in case there is data there so the connections can be reused. Look at the source of `doFollowingRedirects` in the source of `http/client.go` for example.

Comment: Thanks. Its working properly now. Just to clarify - Do I have to close every single redirect response body inside roundtripper, or only the final response - I figured, since I am returning the response, the caller will close it - not the roundtripper. Also, `t.Transport=transport` works, but I dont understand how and why - I went down a completely different path looking at go source code to debug this - before you answered it. Also - isn't it a good idea not to touch the response
body as the caller would want to use it, not the roundtripper ?

Comment: @AbhishekShivanna: You only have to ensure that every Body is closed *eventually*. When you return a response to the client, that becomes the client's responsibility. `t.Transport = transport` is because the `Transport` needs to be assigned for the `CancelRequest` call later on, otherwise it will still be `nil`.

Comment: But why will it be nil - given that I am the one creating the transport wrapper and making the request - does it somehow go out of scope and removed by the time CancelRequest kicks in ?

Comment: @AbhishekShivanna: There's is no scope issue, it's nil because you never assigned it anywhere else. It would be more clear to put it in the constructor anyway -- I'll move the assignment and see if that clarifies things for you.

Comment: Thanks I get it now. We never assigned it so cancel request if ever called would always panic because of the nil. By now putting it in the constructor , I can eliminate that code in the round trip right ?